# Syncing two BindingSources

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a `BindingSource` in my main form, and I have a DataGridView in a User Control. I'd like to use the main form's `BindingSource` on the DGV, but I want to use the designer to customize the columns.

In my attempt, I dragged the same data source onto the user control, which created a new binding source. This let me use the designer to customize the columns. Then, in the code behind, I wrote

```
UserControl.CompaniesBindingSource.DataSource = CompaniesBindingSource
```

This got the data working, but the `Current` property isn't syncing up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I find that trying to use the Visual Studio Designer for the datagridview and manipulate it programmatically in code is very hard. I have never been able to get both to work how I want it to. What I find programmers do is create the datagridview on the form, but they don't do anything with the designer. Then, the entire datagridview is created and manipulated programmatically which, I know, usually takes extensive programming.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. That's a bit discouraging, as indeed I'm trying to get rid of dozens of lines of code + avoid writing future code focused on GUI properties which the designer makes easy to change.